# Is it possible to generate a library-generation project from the command line?

Tags: android

I want to generate a library-generation (`.aar`) project, using the `android` tool from command line.

I know that you can create an application-based project using this command:

```
$ android create project \
    --activity MainActivity \
    --package com.stack.overflow \
    --target API_ID \
    --path /path/to/project
```

The `-h` option says that the `--activity` parameter is required. By definition, a project generating a library won't have any activities.

I know that I can generate an application-generating project, and then change it so that it just generate a library, but is there a way to do it directly from the command line?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `android` tool features a `create lib-project` option. It's used as follow:

```
$ android create lib-project \
    --package com.stack.overflow \
    --target API_ID \
    --path /path/to/project
```